# Cannot get Yii urlManager to work

Tags: yii, url-routing

I am asking this after a couple of hours of searches. I just can't tell what I am missing here. I am trying to set friendly URLs for my Yii application.

1. My base url is http://www.baby-registry.org/BABYREG/app/
2. I am trying to change this url http://www.baby-registry.org/BABYREG/app/index.php?r=generalProducts/admin into http://www.baby-registry.org/BABYREG/app/productAdmin
3. Using this in my main.php config file:

   'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
   'rules'=>array(
   ),
   ),
4. Either with or without rules (tried different rules I found on stackoverflow), this breaks my app altogether, I get the famous notice 'Congratulations! You have successfully created your Yii application.
   You may change the content of this page by modifying the following two files:......'

What am I doing wrong?
Does it have anything to do with the fact that I have a base url like (BABYREG/app)?

Comment: What web server do you use?

Comment: Also show whole UrlManager config's lines

Comment: just to confirm, you have tried this already for the rukes array? 'rules'=>array('productsAdmin'=>'generalProducts/admin' ),

Comment: Did you create the 'required' .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to post a bit more code, and also what error message (if any) you are getting.

But, a common reason for the URL rewriting not to work in Yii is that the apache module [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is off. This apache module is required to use the Yii URL rewriting.

To check whether this module is enabled, in PHP, `use apache_get_modules();` This will return an array of enabled apache modules. So a simple way to check if mode_rewrite is enabled is:

```
if (in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())){
    // mod_rewrite is enabled
}
```

If it is not enabled, ask you hosting company to enable it for you. If you are working on your local host (with WAMP), simply enable it by clicking it under the *apache menu - modules* in the WAMP icon on the system tray

Answer (score 0):

I just spent way too long with my array arguments reversed.  Here's my first successful rewrite:

Link in app:

```
<a href='<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("home"); ?>'>Rewriting test</a>
```

PHP config:

```
'rules'=>array('successfully/rewritten' => 'home');
```

Note that it's *desired url* and then *existing url*.  Backwards, in my head - I'd reckon it's "rewrite this, to this".  Instead, it's "this is the rewrite for this." ^_^